# Using elemMatch to return one object from array node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to query a data collection to return just one object from an array of objects using elemMatch. I have this data:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5ba10e24e1e9f4062801ddeb",
    "user": {
        "_id": "5b9b9097650c3414ac96bacc",
        "firstName": "blah",
        "lastName": "blah blah",
        "email": "blah@gmail.com"
    },
    "appointments": [
        {
            "date": "2018-09-18T14:39:36.949Z",
            "_id": "5ba10e28e1e9f4062801dded",
            "treatment": "LVL",
            "cost": 30
        },
        {
            "date": "2018-09-18T14:39:32.314Z",
            "_id": "5ba10e24e1e9f4062801ddec",
            "treatment": "LVL",
            "cost": 30
        }
    ],
    "__v": 1
}
]
```

I need to query the DB and pull out just one appointment depending on the id passed to params. I am using the code below based on the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch).

```
router.get(
 "/booked/:app_id",
 passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
 (req, res) => {
  Appointment.find()
  .elemMatch("appointments", { id: req.params.app_id })
  .then(app => res.json(app));
 }
);
```

This is returning an empty array though when I test with postman. This is the first time I have used node.js and mongoDB so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you missed the underscore before id : .elemMatch("appointments", { _id: req.params.app_id })

Comment: Thank you @matthPen for pointing that out, silly mistake! Only thing is, after changing that, it now returns the entire data collection and not just the one appointment I need.

Comment: ok, you need only the first array value that matches, that's it? Multiple results are desired/possible, or the first/unique per array is suffisant?

Comment: I need one result which would be the one appointment with the ID that is queried from the params

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are using [elemmatch as query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), but you need to use it as [projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)**

Change your function to this :

```
Appointment.find(
  {"appointments": {$elemMatch: {_id: req.params.app_id }}},
  {"appointments": {$elemMatch: {_id: req.params.app_id }}}
)
```

**Why twice??**

First object in find query param is *$elemmatch query operator*. It will return all documents, that have at least one entry matching _id in there appointments array. (but will return whole documents)

Second object (the same) is *elemmatch projection oprator*, which 'filters' appointments array and returns **only the first matching element** in array.

PS : cannot test this command. Try on your side

Comment: Brilliant, this worked, thank you for the answer and the explanation!

Comment: why removing accepted? 'cause of duplicate, really?

Comment: It was an accident!